# Table cell button issue

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I am facing an issue with a button set in a table cell which covers two rows. it does not fill the second row. how can i make this button fill both rows? I have tried to set height in the style of the button as well as on the table cell itself without success. Please see my code is below: 
1) the css style of the button:

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px #999;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And 2) my html table below:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <button href="#0" class="button" id="cancel_order">Aκύρωση</button>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;" colspan="2">
        <button class="button">Εκτύπωση</button>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <button class="button">Παραγγελία</button>
    </td>
</tr>   

<tr>
    <td style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;" colspan="2">
        <button class="button">Απόδειξη</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can't see the problem here. Anyone else?

Comment: Can you please explain what you want ?

Comment: i have checked it in 4 browsers and the result is the same

Comment: yes let me show you screenshot of the result

Comment: i do not find how to add a screenshot so let me demonstrate it with dots :)

Comment: button 1 (rowspan 2, td) button 2 (td) button 3 (rowspan 2, td)

Comment: button 1 and button 3 i need them to cover both table rows (height=100%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should use css3 [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve this as shown below:

```css
.btn-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-holder .btn-holder {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button class="button" id="cancel_order">Aκύρωση</button>
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <button class="button">Εκτύπωση</button>
    <button class="button">Παραγγελία</button>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Απόδειξη</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i have the <table> tag but i did not paste this piece of code as the table is pretty large

Comment: @A.A.PEACE Yes, I know but i think its a better way to do it instead of using table.

Comment: @A.A.PEACE I've tried to fix it with table but no luck.

Comment: You are TOP. i have inserted your div section in my table in a table row and it worked like a charm

Comment: @A.A.PEACE Please note that IE9 and earlier IE version and some old browser don't support `flexbox` modal.

Comment: yes i know. but hey we can not cover everything. your code works fine and i will target IE9 and up ;) Thanks Bro ... you are saved the day

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/k5wefqz5/1/

Is this your expected result ?

You miss `<table>` tag to complete your code.

Comment: i have the <table> tag but i did not paste this piece of code as the table is pretty large .. .thanks anyway. solved with the below

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
button {height:100%; }
```

Wrap table elements inside a `<table>` in order to get `<td>` and `<tr>` to behave as expected.

#### SNIPPET

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <button href="#0" class="button" id="cancel_order">Aκύρωση</button>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;" colspan="2">
      <button class="button">Εκτύπωση</button>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <button class="button">Παραγγελία</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right:5px; padding-left:5px;" colspan="2">
      <button class="button">Απόδειξη</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @A.A.PEACE Wrap your td and tr in a `<table></table>`, did you look at the Snippet?